# visual studio 2013 mysterious C2228 error

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012

I have recently upgraded some qt projects from vs 2008 to 2013. I am getting a weird

```
Error   1   error C2228: left of '.currentText' must have class/struct/union
```

error when I try access a combo box in my gui.

Here is the code, pretty straight forward:

```
videopanel.h
#ifndef VIDEOPANEL_H
#define VIDEOPANEL_H

#include <QCamera>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QMediaRecorder>
#include <QCameraImageCapture>
#include <QCameraViewFinder>
#include <QVideoWidget>

namespace Ui {
class videoPanel;
}

class videoPanel : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit videoPanel(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~videoPanel();

private slots:
    void monitorToggle(int state);

private:

    Ui::videoPanel *ui;

    QCamera *camera;
    QList<QCameraInfo> cameraInfos;
    QCameraImageCapture *imageCapture;
    QMediaRecorder* mediaRecorder;

    QImageEncoderSettings imageSettings;
    QAudioEncoderSettings audioSettings;
    QVideoEncoderSettings videoSettings;
    QString videoContainerFormat;
    bool isCapturingVideo;

    void setCamera(void);

};

#endif // VIDEOPANEL_H
```

and here is the cpp:
videopanel.cpp

```
#include "videopanel.h"
#include "ui_videopanel.h"

#include <QMediaService>
#include <QMediaRecorder>
#include <QCameraViewfinder>
#include <QCameraInfo>
#include <QMediaMetaData>

#include <iostream>


videoPanel::videoPanel(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::videoPanel),
    camera(0),
    imageCapture(0),
    mediaRecorder(0)
{
    ui->setupUi(this); // fine!!!

    QObject::connect(ui->monitorCheck, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(monitorToggle(int)) );



    // Camera devices:
    cameraInfos = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();
    // display device descriptions in combo box
    for (QList<QCameraInfo>::Iterator it = cameraInfos.begin();
        it != cameraInfos.end(); ++it)
        ui->cameraBox->addItem(it->description()); // fine!!!

}

videoPanel::~videoPanel()
{
    delete mediaRecorder;
    delete imageCapture;
    delete camera;
}

void videoPanel::setCamera(void) {

    delete imageCapture;
    delete mediaRecorder;
    delete camera;


    for (QList<QCameraInfo>::Iterator it = cameraInfos.begin();
        it != cameraInfos.end(); ++it)
        if (!it->description().compare(ui->cameraBox.currentText())) // not fine!!!
            camera = new QCamera(*it);

}


void videoPanel::monitorToggle(int state) {

    if (state == Qt::CheckState::Checked);
    std::cout << ui->cameraBox.currentText() << std::endl; // not fine!!!

}
```

The error I cited above comes at lines 51 and 60, where I try to access `ui`.

So in the constructor, the compiler is fine with the variable `ui`, but not in the other methods. This is pretty boiler plate qt stuff, so I'm not sure what the issue is, but, I suspect there is some flag in VS that is somehow obscuring the scope of my `ui` variable. All my other private variables are ok, so I don't know what the issue is.

I am sure the `uic/moc` process is working properly and I have tried cleaning and rebuilding to no avail.

Comment: What is the type of `cameraBox`? - it is expecting it to be a class/struct. If its a pointer or some other non-class type then you will get this error.

Comment: @logicstuff I simultaneously realized this! 'duh' to me. ui->cameraBox->currentText() did the trick. It's pretty obvious just from looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the lines:

```
if (!it->description().compare(ui->cameraBox.currentText()))
std::cout << ui->cameraBox.currentText() << std::endl;
```

By:

```
if (!it->description().compare(ui->cameraBox->currentText()))
std::cout << ui->cameraBox->currentText() << std::endl;
```